# MySQL query for maximum value of all records from last 5 days

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table:

myTable {Int id, Int value, Date date}

I wish to find the maximum value of all records from last 5 days.

So far I only managed to either get the maximum of all records for this day:

```
SELECT max(`value`) FROM myTable where `date` = CURDATE()
```

or all records from the last 5 days:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE `date` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

How do I get the maximum value of all records from last 5 days?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT MAX(`value`) FROM myTable 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table

```
create temporary table temp_table SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE `date` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Then

```
select max('value') from temp_table;
```